# If user's answer is NaN, alert NaN and ask again for a number

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I'm writing a function that asks a user for a number and returns the sqrt of that number. If they don't provide a number I need to alert(NaN) and prompt for a number again. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, it is returning the sqrt but I can't get the NaN part to work.

```js
function sqrtUserNum() {
  let userNum = parseFloat(prompt("Give me a number and I'll tell you it's square-root."));
  if (isNaN(userNum)) {
    alert(NaN)
    prompt(userNum)
  }
  if (!isNaN(userNum)); {
    alert(Math.sqrt(userNum))
  }
}
sqrtUserNum()
```

Comment: Please explain in what way(s) it does not work: what should it do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: Is this what you want  `alert("NaN")`?

Comment: I'll respond to your question by asking you another one. What's wrong with this code? `if (!isNaN(userNum)) {} alert(Math.sqrt(userNum))`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how you're prompting again with this `prompt(userNum)`

- First, extract the prompt part.
- I recommend you to use `do-while-loop` for looping and ask for a number when is not a number.
- Use the object `Number` instead to avoid problems with strings like this `4yryr`

```js
function askFor() {
  return Number(prompt("Give me a number and I'll tell you it's square-root."));
}

function sqrtUserNum() {
  let userNum;
  do {
    userNum = askFor();

    if (isNaN(userNum)) {
      alert(NaN);
    } else {
      alert(Math.sqrt(userNum))
    }    
  } while (isNaN(userNum));
}
sqrtUserNum();
```

Answer (score 1):

As comments have pointed out, you have typos in the code. What you probably are trying to achieve is something like:

```js
function sqrtUserNum() {
  let userNum;

  for (;;) {
    userNum = parseFloat(prompt("Give me a number and I'll tell you it's square-root."));
    if (!isNaN(userNum))
      break;
    alert("The number was not valid!");
  }

  alert(Math.sqrt(userNum));
}

sqrtUserNum()
```

In other words, you want to alert the user that the number was invalid and try again, until you get an actual number.

Answer (score 0):

Programming is a good bit about following grammar rules, and the following is 'dubious':

```
if (!isNaN(userNum)); {
  alert(Math.sqrt(userNum))
}
```

This is because the extra `;` causes it to be parsed as:

```
if (!isNaN(userNum)) /* do nothing */;

/* block unrelated to conditional, which is always executed */
{
  alert(Math.sqrt(userNum))
}
```

See the [Block Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)

Answer (score 0):

At first, you had some typos in your code.

If you want to keep requesting a number if the user does not enter one, I modified your script to do exactly that. (I can't really tell from your question):

```js
function sqrtUserNum() {
  let userNum = parseFloat(prompt("Give me a number and I'll tell you it's square-root."));
  while (isNaN(userNum)) {
    alert("NaN");
    userNum = parseFloat(prompt("Please enter a number."));
  }
  alert(Math.sqrt(userNum));
}
sqrtUserNum();
```

---

In case you do not want to do that, this should do it:

```js
function sqrtUserNum() {
  let userNum = parseFloat(prompt("Give me a number and I'll tell you it's square-root."));
  if (isNaN(userNum)) {
    alert("NaN");
    userNum = parseFloat(prompt("Give me a number and I'll tell you it's square-root."));
  }
  if (!isNaN(userNum)) {
    alert(Math.sqrt(userNum));
  }
}
sqrtUserNum();
```